# Granger causality and variance decomposition yield conflicting results

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality, variance-decomposition

I am analyzing a VAR model with 8 variables and 12 lags. 
When analyzing Granger causality test - it seems there is no relationship between some of the key variables, monetary policy rate and loan rate. On the other hand, when analyzing the decomposition of the forecast error variance, the results are that monetary policy rate contributes 15% to the variance of the loans rate, which I want to prove and which is relatively high compared to the variance of other variables. The irf function shows that when policy rate increases for 1 unit, the loans rate also increases for 4 periods and than decreases again.
Do the tests give opposite results? Do the results nullify themselves?